# How would I find the interval centered about x=0 for which the given IVP has a unique solution:

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

How would I find the interval centered about x=0 for which the given IVP has a unique solution:
$$(x-2)y''+3y=x$$
With the initial conditions of $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$

The answer is supposedly $(-\infty,2)$. How do I show work for this problem? Or better yet how do I understand it. I believe the DE is homogeneous, and I plugged the DE into Wolfram, and got a complicated output. Any thoughts would be helpful.

### My Attempts/Thoughts

To at least attempt, I would say dived the whole thing by $(x-2)$ yielding:
$$y''+\frac{3y}{x-2}=\frac{x}{x-2}$$
Making 2 not being a number that can be plugged in...

Comment: Do you know any existence-uniqueness theorems for DEs?

Comment: @user764828 I have this Theorem Let $a_n(x),a_{n-1}(x),a_0(x), \ \text{and} \ g(x)$ be continuous on an interval I, and let $a_n(x)\ne0$ for every x in this interval. If $x=x_0$ is any point in this interval, then a solution $y(x)$ of the IVP exists on the interval and is unique.

Comment: @user764828 Does this help?

Comment: It might, but you haven't explained what the theorem actually is. What are $a_n(x), a_{n-1}(x), a_0(x),$ and $g(x)$, and how do they relate to $y(x)$? What equation does $y(x)$ satisfy? Also, I'm wondering if there's supposed to be an $a_1(x), a_2(x), \ldots, a_{n-2}(x)$ as well?

Comment: @user764828 No because I have this textbook, and I am quite lost myself, thats the only theorem in the section.  I believe that they are solutions to the DE, which in my case I don't have in this problem.

Comment: Well, let me tell you my guess, and see if you think that this is what the textbook means. I think the theorem is, the equation$$a_n(x)y^{(n)}(x)+a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}(x)+\ldots+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=g(x),$$i.e. a linear equation, and we are to suppose the coefficients $a_i(x)$, as well as $g(x)$, are continuous on $I$, where $a_n(x)\neq0$ on $I$. Then the equation has a unique solution. Does that seem right?

Comment: @user764828 Yes. That seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

let $$(x-2)y=u(x)$$ So $$y+(x-2)y'=u'$$  $$2y'+(x-2)y''=u''$$
Then $$(x-2)y''+3y=x  => $$
$$u''-2y'+3y=x$$
$$u''-2u'/(x-2)+2u/(x-2)^2+3u/(x-2)=x $$
Finally
$$(x-2)^2u''-2(x-2)u'+3(x-2)u+2u=x(x-2)^2$$
Now continue...